# Why the "while" concurrent is running slower and slower in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I want zip lots of files using more cpus at onetime by using shell's concurrent function like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

function zip_data()
{
while true
do
{
echo "do zip something" 
}&
done
}

zip_data  
wait
```

**At the begin time ,the speed of loop onetime is  quickly .
But with the increase of  loop times when running, 
the speed is more and more slowly.
Why ???**

I think the reason may be there are too many child processes are runing .
So I try that make the  while function  running  one loop  at onetime like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

function trap_exit
{
exec 1000>&-;exec 1000<&-
kill -9 0
}

trap 'trap_exit; exit 2' 1 2 3 15 9

mkfifo testfifo ; exec 1000<>testfifo ; rm -rf testfifo

function zip_data()
{
echo >&1000

while true
read -u 1000
do
{
echo "do something" 
echo >&1000 
}&
done
}

zip_data 
wait
```

However the phenomenon is same like before .

So I don't understand that reason  why the speed is more and more slowly when runing.

#

Today  I try like this but it don't work

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
c=0
while true
do
        c=$(jobs -p | wc -l)
        while [ $c -ge 20 ]; do
                c=$(jobs -p | wc -l)
                sleep 0.01
        done

        {
        echo "$c" 
        sleep 0.8
        }&


done
```

So i try other way to finish this function like this ,Thank you!

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

function EXPECT_FUNC()
{
para=$1 
while true
do
{
do something $1
}
done

}

EXPECT_FUNC 1 &
EXPECT_FUNC 2 &
EXPECT_FUNC 3 &
EXPECT_FUNC 4 &


wait
```

Comment: You've still got a fork bomb, and `echo "do something"` is writing into the fifo formerly linked by `testfifo`

Comment: Yes,I know that the "echo" command  is  a child process ,but why the virt and res is increasing even that  the child processes exit after loop .

Comment: Because you are spawning processes with no limit, and the are getting created faster than they are being terminated.  Your attempt to limit the child creation with the fifo is failing because "do something" is getting written into the fifo.

Comment: Your I/O won't go faster zipping a lot of files concurrently.

Comment: Thank you ,I understand it and use other way to finish the function.

Answer (score 2):

Any single-threaded util can run in well managed concurrent threads with [parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).  `man parallel` offers dozens of examples, e.g.:

```
   Create a directory for each zip-file and unzip it in that dir:

       parallel 'mkdir {.}; cd {.}; unzip ../{}' ::: *.zip

   Recompress all .gz files in current directory using bzip2 running 1 job
   per CPU core in parallel:

       parallel "zcat {} | bzip2 >{.}.bz2 && rm {}" ::: *.gz
```

A particularly interesting example that only works with `gzip` shows how to use several CPUs to simultaneously work *one* archive, with a *single-threaded* archiver, which sounds impossible:

```
    To process a big file or some output you can use --pipe to split up 
    the data into blocks and pipe the blocks into the processing program.

    If the program is gzip -9 you can do:

        cat bigfile | parallel --pipe --recend '' -k gzip -9 >bigfile.gz

    This will split bigfile into blocks of 1 MB and pass that to 
    gzip -9 in parallel. One gzip will be run per CPU core. The output
    of gzip -9 will be kept in order and saved to bigfile.gz
```

If `parallel` is too complex, here are some compression utils with built-in parallel archiving:

- XZ:   [pixz](https://github.com/vasi/pixz)
- LZMA: [plzip](http://www.nongnu.org/lzip/plzip.html), [pxz](https://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/pxz/)
- GZIP: [pigz](http://zlib.net/pigz/)
- BZIP2: [pbzip2](http://compression.ca/pbzip2/)

Comment: Thank you ,My server don't contain this patallel soft .So i use other way to finish.